Why are dependencies installed during the Docker build step not available in the final container?
I am trying to build a Docker image for my application. During the build process, I install all the necessary dependencies (e.g., via npm install), and the installation step completes successfully. However, when I run the container, the dependencies seem to be missing.
Here’s an example of my Dockerfile:
Stage 1: Build dependencies
FROM node:18 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

Stage 2: Create final image
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app /app

Questions:
Is there something wrong with my COPY --from=build command in the Dockerfile?
Do I need to configure something additional in a multi-stage build to ensure the dependencies persist into the final image?
Are there other debugging steps I can take to determine why the dependencies are not being included?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

How about building one container instead of two containers? FROM node:18 will start over from scratch ...

@MartinZeitler Well, that seems to be the purpose of it. RUN npm install   also creates a npm cache directory in the image. And by starting with a fresh image and copying over only the installed packages from the previous stage, the final image does not contain that needless data

Your setup doesn't seem to contain the actual application code; how does that get into the image?  Many Node setups in particular seem set on injecting code via Compose volumes: rather than using Docker's reusable image system, and with Node's standard filesystem layout, this will hide the node_modules library tree in the image.

If you have something like volumes: [.:/app], it hides everything in the container's /app directory – the code, any RUN npm ci libraries, anything generated by a RUN npm run build or similar step – and replaces it with whatever happens to be on the current user's host machine.  If you have a Compose volumes: block or docker run -v option like that, you should probably delete it.

Is there actually any code to copy in the source stage? From your example the wildcard copy could fail to find any files, meaning the /app directory will be empty in both stages

The second one FROM statement would need to refer to the previously built image, not the node:18 base image, which equals the starting point of the first stage... the instruction FROM node:18 does exactly what it says.; the second reference would need to be eg. FROM build (or whatever alias-name had been assigned to the previous stage). For example:
FROM node:18 AS baseimage
...


FROM baseimage
...

Generally speaking, the alias-name is key to create the continuation without starting over.
https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage
As my example shows, the alias-name is only required when there are further stages, where one has to refer to the previous stage; when it's only two stages, the second stage doesn't necessarily require an alias-name (while the example in the documentation has more than just two stages).
